# Windows XP drivers for Ardiuno Uno

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Is there a Windows XP driver for the FTDI-chip on the Arduino Uno?
The drivers from the Arduino development package don't work and the drivers from this page (http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm) also don't work, even those which should be for XP.
How is the FTDI-chip called which is on the Arduino Uno?

Answer (score 0):

The Uno has changed FTDI chip by exchanging the FT232RL chip with an atmega8u2 chip. Basically the driver you need is contained in the Uno IDE instrallation.

Here is the procedure to install it on Windows XP.
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/UnoDriversWindowsXP